# postgres doesnt restart after making the necessary .conf file changes

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

apologies first. On a steep learning curve more like a wall and will be verbose and lacking in jargon but too old to change that now. I'm trying to access a Postgresql-13 (with postgis-3 extensions) database from a machine other than the one where it is hosted. Before doing anything at all other than install, create and consume a spatial data file, this is the partial screen dump from

`sudo netstat -ltpn`

| Proto | Recv-Q | Send-Q | Local Address | Foreign Address | State | PID/Program name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tcp | 0 | 0 | 127.0.0.1:5432 | 0.0.0.0:* | LISTEN | 993/postgres |

... and the database is accessible from pgadmin4 on the Ubuntu 20.04 machine which is hosting it. I can also connect to the database in QGIS on the same Ubuntu machine through 127.0.0.1 and port 5432. Nothing special about that other than knowing it works. What I want to do is connect to that database from any machine running QGIS (or another GIS platform which can consume postgis).

Port forwarding rules on the router are set for 80, 8080 and 5900 to point to 10.0.0.55 which is the IP for the Ubuntu 20.04 which is hosting. I have a dynamic DNS pointing the routers IP to give it the name http://blah.blah.net (not actually that, but close).

pgadmin4 is installed and configured to run in server and I can access the database through pgadmin4 from the host or any other computer using http://blah.blah.net/pgadmin4. Not sure I got this config quite right but it works. Geoserver is also running smoothly on Tomcat9 accessible from anywhere through http://blah.blah.net:8080/Geoserver/web/. And a fancy front end in the making on http://blah.blah.net.

Have then done the following mods to the two .conf files in `etc/postgresql/13/main` which are well noted and documented already ...

`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

in the `pg_hba.conf`

and also ...

`listen_addresses='*'` (and removed the leading #)

`port = 5432` (was already)

in the `postgresql.conf`

Then restarted postgres with ...

`sudo service postgresql restart`

... and then port 5432 disappears completely and the database is not accessible from anywhere. Not even the host computer. Checked that postgresql was running with ...

`sudo systemctl status postgresql`

... which it appears to be. But am getting nothing from QGIS or pgadmin4. Not even from the host machine.

Got a lot of questions but the most obvious is am I missing something? Not sure if I need a rule at the router for port 5432 - did try that in a similar fashion to the rules above but it didn't change anything. Appreciate any help. Cheers ... R

Answer (score 0):

The local address in the `netstat` output:

```
127.0.0.1:5432
```

indicates that PostgreSQL is only listening on the loopback interface. Since you changed `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf`, I conclude that you forgot to restart PostgreSQL.

To confirm, run this query:

```
SELECT setting, pending_restart
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name = 'listen_addresses';
```

It should either show the wrong value (if you didn't reload or changed the wrong file altogether) or show `pending_restart` as `TRUE` (if you reloaded, but didn't restart).

Comment: Thank you this has helped. I ran the query and got localhost and false. Not unexpected. Then I decided to change the conf files separately. The postgresql.conf first with the listen_addresses = '*". Restart service and it was still connected to pgadmin4. Listening to 0.0.0.0/5432. Run query again gave * and false. On to the pg_hba.conf and changed host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5 to host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 and restart. Now connection is lost and 5432 is not showing up on netstat. This is where the problem is. Question now if you dont mind - how do I get it to listen to 0.0.0.0:5432 again?

Comment: It will show up, unless there is an error binding the address, which would show up in the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: From this, something is up with the pg_hba.conf. I set it back to chown root:root (path) after finishing mods. AEST [21154] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
AEST [21154] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
AEST [21154] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
AEST [21154] LOG:  could not open configuration file "/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf": Permission denied
AEST [21154] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
AEST [21154] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server

Comment: changed ownership of pg_hba.conf to user postgres has fixed it.